# iOS - isViewLoaded crash

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

I have a code that checks if an internet connection is there. If there is no internet, I display an alert. Here is the code:

```
- (void)testInternetConnection
{
    __unsafe_unretained typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    internetReachableFoo = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.your-voc.com"];

    // Internet is reachable
    internetReachableFoo.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            internetActivated = YES;
            NSLog(@"Yayyy, we have the interwebs!");
        });
    };

    // Internet is not reachable
    internetReachableFoo.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            internetActivated = NO;
            if(alertLoaded == NO){
                if(weakSelf.isViewLoaded && weakSelf.view.window){
                    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pas de connexion internet" message:@"Une connexion est requise pour utiliser l'application" delegate:weakSelf cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Réessayer", @"Mode hors-ligne", nil];
                    [alert show];
                    alertLoaded = YES;
                }
            }
            NSLog(@"Someone broke the internet :(");
        });
    };

    [internetReachableFoo startNotifier];
}
```

I use the isViewLoaded and view.window to be sure to only display the alert if the current window is the one that is loaded and displayed.

But some times, when I shut down the wifi, my simulator crashes with the following error;

```
-[UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer isViewLoaded]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbe73da4060
2014-12-05 14:16:57.142 [838:117938] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer isViewLoaded]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbe73da4060'
```

What is wrong?

Thanks a lot

UPDATE: I use Tony Million's version of Reachability, so the testInternetConnection method is called whenever the internet status changes.

Comment: Can you please add more code? Like how you are calling this method?

Comment: There you go, updated code.

Comment: Did you  try __strong typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

Comment: Yes but I get a warning that it may lead to a retain cycle in this block. Is that OK?

Comment: It's not OK. You shouldn't do that because it will keep your old object in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your `weakSelf` variable is probably a weak pointer and is already released when code reaches this point.

Comment: Looking at the updated code, what do you think? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, the object that has `testInternetConnection` method is released. No problem with Reachability class. We need to see where do you call `testInternetConnection` and over with object.

Comment: I call my testInternetConnection in viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear!

Comment: Then, your `ViewController` object is released from memory. Maybe you have popped it from navigation stack. You should move your `testInternetConnection` method to somewhere that is more application wide, for example `Application Delegate`.